# maven compile with custom folder and add to an artifact

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

I am trying to manage a client specific resources and classes. I come up with following project structure.

[image: folder structure]

I would like to know that is it a correct way to manage them and also i would like to add my custom folder to an artifact and compile them as well. I have used in my POM but it helps me to compile not to package.

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>src/clients</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

i have used below one too but it helps me to package

```
<resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/clients</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
```

when i use mvn spring-boot:run, i am getting an error called

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat

Comment: Have you tried using both of them at once?

Comment: no i have used either one of them

Comment: Use them together

Comment: i tried that too but didnt work